# What, if anything, do Gabriel's bracelets signify?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

In the movie *Constantine*, during the climax in the mental hospital, Gabriel is shown wearing many hospital bracelets.

[image: Constantine and Gabriel]

**What, if anything, do these bracelets signify?**

Neither [the official novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Constantine-John-Shirley/dp/0743497554) nor [the original script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Constantine.html) mention Gabriel's costume.

The question has been asked over on the Movies & TV Stack: ["Gabriel's Wristbands in Constantine"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2310/9382). Alas, most answers it has received are speculation without source<sup>‡</sup>. However, they *do* establish that the bracelets read "Awakening", "Sorrow", "Rage", "Passion", "Love", "Joy", and "Melancholy".

---

<sup>‡ I've since added a copy of the answer I've accepted here, over there.</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the film's director (on the [disk audio commentary](http://www.dvdmg.com/constantine.shtml)), the hospital bracelets signify **various human '*aspects*' and were written by Gabriel in order to remind him why he's doing what he's doing.**

The original idea was to have writing *directly onto Tilda Swinton's arms*. The bands were a last-minute addition to the costume at Swinton's urging.

> **Francis Lawrence**: *These bracelets, which are hospital bracelets, which... This was something that I thought of because I was imagining originally, I was going to write on my arms, like, notes. Kind of Travis Bickle in the last scene, you know ... A few notes about actually what the revolution's all about. And so **they have a variety of different aspects written on them**. That was her idea, which I thought was fantastic.*
>
> *It was just this really subtle thing. I liked the image just of all the hospital bracelets lined up but then when you see sort of **all the words that are sort of the reasons for why she's doing what she's doing**. I thought was just fantastic. **Just to remind Gabriel if Gabriel has any doubts what humanity's about or, you know, why it's all worth it.***

Comment: So basically it's Gabriel's self-convincing that it's the right thing to do. It's also funny that they say "she", as in the actress, while speaking about the character.

Comment: @Clockwork - In this instance, the director appears to be conflating Tilda Swinton ("her idea") with Gabriel. He's pretty consistent otherwise in the commentary.

Answer (score 9):

As John Constantine constantly reminds everyone, Gabriel is a [half-breed](https://constantine.wikia.com/wiki/Half-Breed) - part human, part angel.  Gabriel wears five hospital bracelets on one arm:

[image: Gabriel raising a knife - five hospital bracelets are seen]

And we know that one says "Passion" and another says "Sorrow"

[image: Close up on hospital bracelets]

There are others, but I can't read them.

[image: Gabriel in hospital outfit]

In any case, all the words people have claimed to have seen -  "Awakening", "Sorrow", "Rage", "Passion", "Love", "Joy", and "Melancholy" - are human emotions, aside from "Awakening".  This seems to be a reference to Gabriel's status as a half-breed, which makes her more prone to the vagaries of human emotion than a true angel would be.  It is also possible that it is intended to foreshadow her imminent demotion to 'mere human' status.

Answer (score 1):

His entire outfit has a 'mental hospital' theme to it, being that it looks like it's something made out of a straitjacket. Likely the entire outfit, armbands included, symbolize Gabriel's insanity. Because he hasn't turned evil, he has actually just gone insane.

Comment: This seems like pure speculation

Comment: More pure speculation, but it always looked like a riff on a fighter pilot's G-suit to me. I have no idea what the symbolism of that is.