# In Constantine, what were the ring-like items Isabel threw?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

In *Constantine*, what did Isabel drop before her suicide? It looks like a pair of rings.

What was the meaning of throwing them off the roof first?

Comment: No prob. Welcome to [fantasy.se]! Do you by any chance know [what Gabriel's bracelets signify?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91823/19561)

Comment: @SQB thanks, and I've wondered what those hospital bracelets meant too. I don't know but I just read your post. I've always thought it was just part of the costume. Gabriel and Lucifer had Awesome outfits, creative and modern for the movie. So I thought the hospital bracelets were a cool addition to the whole outfit for him/her.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A closer inspection reveals them to be two heavy metal loops, presumably those used by the building's window cleaners to attach their materials to the roof.

[image: metalloops hitting the ground]

Note that she didn't throw them, she accidentally kicked them off. In the original script it was a bottle but I'm guessing the filmmakers struggled to explain why there was a bottle sitting on the roof edge whereas "*random roof stuff*" makes more sense.

> XT. ROOFTOP - NIGHT
>
> A metal fire door swings open and Angela bursts out --
>   breathing deep. She runs across the tar roof, almost
>   afraid to look back.
>   She gets to the ledge, steps up.   A BOTTLE in the way
>   fall[s] -- FOLLOW IT DOWN TO the --
>
> COURTYARD
>
> -- where it SHATTERS --

[image: roof at night]

Comment: Ahh! Thanks this is great! I can totally see them now and definitely not rings.

Comment: @HJPark - The benefits of having access to the Bluray

Answer (score 0):

They are a shackle and a wire rope clamp.  These are used for rigging when lifting something.  As someone previously noted, probably supplies left behind by a window cleaning crew.